# PHP nested array to HTML Table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i have the following nested array:

```
  'МУЖСКАЯ ОДЕЖДА LIFE IS GOOD' => 
array(
  'Российские размеры' => 
  array(
    '42', '44', '46', '48', '50', '52', '54'
    ), 
    'РАЗМЕРЫ SML' => 
    array(
      'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'
      ), 
      'Рост (для джоггеров)' => 
      array(
    '-', '-', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194'
    ), 
    'Обхват груди' => 
    array(
    'измеряется горизонтально по выступающим точкам груди вокруг тела' => 
    array(
    'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
    array(
      '90-93', '94-97', '98-101', '102-105', '106-110'
      ), 
      'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
    array(
    '84-86', '86-91', '91-97', '97-102', '102-107', '107-114', '114-122'
    )
    )
    ), 
    'Обхват талии' => 
    array(
    'измеряется не затягивая вокруг талии' => 
    array(
      'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
      array(
        '78-81','82-85','86-89','90-93','94-98'
        ), 
        'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
        array(
        '66-71','71-76','76-81','81-86','86-91','91-99','99-107'
        )
      )
    ),
      'Обхват бедер' => 
    array(
    'измерительная лента проодит по самым выступающим местам ягодиц' => 
    array(
      'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
      array(
        '96-100','101-103','104-106','107-109','110-114'
        ), 
        'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
        array(
        '84-86','86-91','91-97','97-102','102-107','107-114','114-122'
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  'ЖЕНСКАЯ ОДЕЖДА LIFE IS GOOD' => array(
  'Российские размеры' => 
  array(
    '42', '44', '46', '48', '50', '52', '54'
    ), 
    'РАЗМЕРЫ SML' => 
    array(
      'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'
      ), 
      'Рост (для джоггеров)' => 
      array(
    '-', '-', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194', '182/194'
    ), 
    'Обхват груди' => 
    array(
    'измеряется горизонтально по выступающим точкам груди вокруг тела' => 
    array(
    'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
    array(
      '90-93', '94-97', '98-101', '102-105', '106-110'
      ), 
      'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
    array(
    '84-86', '86-91', '91-97', '97-102', '102-107', '107-114', '114-122'
    )
    )
    ), 
    'Обхват талии' => 
    array(
    'измеряется не затягивая вокруг талии' => 
    array(
      'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
      array(
        '78-81','82-85','86-89','90-93','94-98'
        ), 
        'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
        array(
        '66-71','71-76','76-81','81-86','86-91','91-99','99-107'
        )
      )
    ),
      'Обхват бедер' => 
    array(
    'измерительная лента проодит по самым выступающим местам ягодиц' => 
    array(
      'Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' => 
      array(
        '96-100','101-103','104-106','107-109','110-114'
        ), 
        'Куртка, жилет утепленные, куртка трикотажная' => 
        array(
        '84-86','86-91','91-97','97-102','102-107','107-114','114-122'
        )
      )
    )
  )));
```

I wanted to convert it into an html table that would look like this
[image]

I have tried to recursively loop through:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
  function printNestedArray($a,$table_row = true) {
  if($table_row){
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
      echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars("$key: ") . '</td></tr>';
      if (is_array($value)) {
        printNestedArray($value,false);
      } else {
        echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td></tr>';
      }
    }
  }else{
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
      echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars("$key: ") . '</td>';
      if (is_array($value)) {
        printNestedArray($value);
      } else {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
      }
    }
  }
}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone , somehow get the result done? maybe some ideas of how? I would be very grateful , this is one of the tasks i have to get done until tomorrow but i have an intuition that this is gonna last long

Comment: Where is the question? What do you need to do?

Comment: Convert your example input data (array) to JSON format, so it will be more compact and easier to read it here.

Comment: `Трикотажные изделия (худи, джоггеры, футболки)' =>  array(  '90-93', '94-97', '98-101', '102-105', '106-110'),` this part is impossible to render. There is no information that we need to skip 1 cell, then print, then skip last cell in a table.

Comment: Your sample array produces errors (and is unreadable with the current formatting). Please ensure you provide code we can easily read and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is irregular - no recursive option. Worse - second part is a copy of first, values should be different. My code output is formatted as in your picture. `$array` it is your array (I hope, with correct values)

```
function noodavai($arr){
    $space0 = $space1 = '<td></td><td></td>';
    $simple = array_merge(range(0,3),range(10,13));
    $i = 0;
    foreach($arr as $thkey=>$thval){
        echo"<table><tr><th colspan='10'>$thkey</th></tr>\r\n";
        foreach($thval as $key=>$value){
            $i++;
            if(in_array($i,$simple)){   echo"<tr><td>$key</td>$space0"; foreach($value as $val){    echo"<td>$val</td>";}   echo"</tr>\r\n";}
            else{
                echo "<tr><td rowspan='2'>$key</td>";
                foreach($value as $ke=>$val){   echo "<td rowspan='2' class='grey'>$ke</td>";
                    foreach($val as $k=>$v){    echo ($i%2 == 0) ? "<td>$k</td>$space1" : "<td class='grey'>$k</td>";
                        foreach($v as $x){  echo"<td>$x</td>";} if($i%2 == 0){  echo $space2; $i++;}    echo"</tr>\r\n";}}}}
    echo"</table>\r\n";
    $i++;
    $space1 = $space2 = '<td></td>';}}

noodavai($array);
```